# How do I access values using kint()?

Tags: debugging

I am porting a module from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8. I was debugging using `kint()`.

I am using `hook_user_presave($account)` and trying to access the values of `$account` using `kint($account)`.

[image: screenshot]

`kint()` is very confusing, compared to dsm() in Drupal 7.

How do I access values using `kint()`?

Comment: Just as an aside: it's not really kint that causes the confusion (krumo, used by `dpm` in D7, would show you the same thing), it's more the fact that pretty much everything's changed since D7. You're now dumping out typed classes more often than not, and because of the way debugger output works, and in some cases the fact that magic methods have been used, you're not necessarily going to see everything you're used to seeing. If you haven't already, hunt out some tutorials/articles on the new entity/field system in D8; reading a few of those will help immensely with future debugging

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user entity from the proxy with [`AccountProxy::getAccount`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountProxy.php/function/AccountProxy%3A%3AgetAccount/8.3.x):

```
$entity = $account->getAccount();
```

And then the roles with [`User::getRoles`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetRoles/8.3.x):

```
$roles = $entity->getRoles;
```

If you don't need the entity for anything else in that method, it turns into a one-liner:

```
$roles = $account->getAccount()->getRoles();
```